# Newline in alt text

Tags: html, xhtml

Can I use some sort of line break in the alt text for an image while still adhering to the XHTML 1.0 Strict standard?

Something like this...

```
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="Line 1\nLine 2" />
```

I'm asking because I want to post the following screenshot on my site, but I want to include the text-only version in the alt text for SEO reasons and for the visually impaired.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/563df.png]

I prefer the screenshot over the plain text version because it looks more visually appealing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use a normal line break.

```
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="Line 1
Line 2" />
```

Stack Overflow does this in their titles :)

Then add this CSS:

```
img{white-space:pre}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/S8SXP/

Comment: The CSS is only needed if you want the alt displayed with line breaks, in the case that the image is not found.

Comment: This appears to violate the XHTML 1.0 Strict standard.

Comment: Hmm, I tested in the validator and got "This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Strict!"

Comment: The white-space property is not supported in IE or IE Mobile, iOS Safari beyond 7.0, or Android beyond 4.4

Comment: @Pieter: any reference to support your point above please (... violates the XHTML 1.0 Strict standard)? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Just try it out in the W3C Validator. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/peteydiddles/7twskyz4/

Comment: It is better to use   white-space: pre-line; instead of "hard" pre;

Answer (score 10):

A better way is to just add the HTML character code for line feed or carriage return.

```
 line feed is &#10
 carriage return &#13
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org will give you an error if "a numeric character reference expanded to carriage return."

Comment: This is not very cross-compatible.  Wasn't able to get this to work in any of my browsers.

Comment: doesn't work in chrome

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be trying too hard.
The alt text is supposed to be a replacement for the image, not some kind of literal representation of it.

Properly marked up and so on, this would be say an unordered list with sub-lists, and a screen-reader would get relationship information from that nesting of HTML elements. Replacing that with some line breaks to get a rough visual approximation isn't nearly the same thing, eg. how do you plan to also "show" the screenreader that the chunk after the first line break is "inside" the Errors?
And I doubt search engines are going to do anything with line breaks in alt text other than discard them. (Admittedly speculative.)

What you're *actually* after is somehow including that nesting/relationship information the image has, but with text instead. Start with something like "A screenshot of notices from [app], showing two errors [detail here if you want] and two informational items [detail]" etc.

Or you could get really pedantic and actually create the list in HTML, then use an image replacement technique to insert the image.

Comment: I found this on image replacement... http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=124 Image replacement seems a good solution for static websites, but I use the WordPress CMS. Is there a way to automate this process a little bit more? Cuz it's not realistic having to edit my stylesheet every time I use this technique.

Answer (score 0):

@Murch's answer was something I didnt know.
However it becomes and overhead to break whitespaces to BRs all throughout the app.

As the simplest solution, you can just provide

```
img.class { overflow:hidden }
```

and get over with it quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

For me `img { white-space: pre; }` was not viable because it stopped the alt text from wrapping and made it spill out of the image boundaries (chromium on debian). The solution I used instead was to add lots of `&nbsp;`s until the text went to the next line. Hopefully screen readers will just ignore this as whitespace.