# img alt text is not displayed when it is long

Tags: html, css, image, width, alt

I have two images in the html email. When images are not displayed, the alt text is expected to be shown. Right?

```
  <img src="invalid url" border="0" alt="AAA BBBB AAA BBBB 123456789" style="width:237px;height:100px;">
  <img src="invalid url" border="0" alt="AAA BBBB AAA BBBB 1234567890" style="width:237px;height:100px;">
```

However, when the text is longer than the dimensions of the image, it is not displayed at all.
As result, it is displayed for the first image and not displayed for the second one.
Is there any way to display the text in several lines if it is longer, or to display the first part of the text?

**Added: this happens for Google Chrome. For the Firefox the alt is displayed.**

Comment: I can see alt text for both the images. can you provide browser details, where you are facing issue?

Comment: Just added the bold text to the question. FF displays it fine. Chrome is a problem.

Comment: Please refer given [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386570/how-to-display-alt-text-for-an-image-in-chrome

seems this is the issue with chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can break `alt` text in new line (meaning it's not generated dynamically) a simple idea to have `alt` text in new line is :

```
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="Line 1
Line 2" /> <br > // new line here is next line for alt text
```

So for your case :

```
<img src="invalid url" border="0" alt="AAA BBBB 
AAA BBBB 
123456789" style="width:237px;height:100px;">
```

Reference : [Newline in alt text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770082/newline-in-alt-text)

Comment: Thank you. However, in my case it doesn't work as the alt text is generated (is taken from the db). Is it possible to fix this with css / html only? Thanks.

Comment: m afraid that's not possible (atleast in my knowledge)....because even `<br>`is not accepted as a tag in `<alt>` string! :(

Comment: @Haradzieniec : looks like some `webkit` issue, please check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386570/how-to-display-alt-text-for-an-image-in-chrome

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't know the behavior of such basic html things from 1990's is so different for different browsers even in 2013.

Comment: haha..couldn't agree more sir....bhvr is changing...`webkit`,`moz` and then nightmare IE! ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in your code, This might be bug in webkit ([Source](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5566)). Chrome, Safari and other webkit browsers will not show you the alt text.
There is nothing you can do for this. Even if you try with *title* attribute, it will not work.